# ld can not find symbol _start error after assemble and link .asm file to 64 bit executables

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, gdb, ld

I have a shellcode file. 
Then use ndisasm to build the assembly code.

```
 ndisasm -b 64 shellcode > shellcode.asm 
 cat shellcode.asm | cut -c29->key.asm
```

I add 2 lines to the key.asm file

> global_start:
>        _start:

```
$vi key.asm
global_start:
_start:
xor eax,eax
push rax
push qword 0x79237771
push qword 0x76772427
push qword 0x25747320
.    .     .
.    .     .
.    .     .
push qword 0x20757577
push rsp
pop rsi
mov edi,esi
mov edx,edi
cld
mov ecx,0x80
mov ebx,0x41
xor eax,eax
push rax
lodsb
xor eax,ebx
```

An then I assemble and link it to 64 bit executables

```
$nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs key.asm 
$ld -o key key.o
```

It gives me a warning

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400080
```

I tested it out with gcc

```
gcc -o key key.o
```

I still get an error almost the same as the first one

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In 
function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And when I run ./key with gdb after I use $ld NOT $gcc

```
$gdb -q ./key
$run
```

I get a seg fault

```
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/owner/Documents/U
M/Computer_Security/ExtraCredit/key
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040013a in global_start ()
```

If I debug after run with gcc then the file will not be found because of exit status

Can you explain why does it happen? And how can I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: You have a missing space in `global_start:` (between `global` and `_start` and there should be no colon on the end (remove it). It should be `global _start`

Comment: You segfault on `lodsb` because you truncated a stack address with `mov edi,esi` instead of `mov rdi, rsi`.  And if you fix that then you fall off the end of your code into garbage instructions because you don't make an `exit` system call.  You're already running this inside `gdb`, use it!

Answer (score 3):

> It gives me a warning
>
> ```
> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400080
> ```

This isn't actually a problem, as long as you're fine with the entry point being the start of the text segment (i.e. the first instruction in your shellcode).

You got the error because you left out the space between the `global` keyword and the `_start` symbol name.  i.e. use `global _start`, or don't bother.  What you did defined a label called `global_start`, as you can see from your later error message.

---

You segfault on `lodsb` because you truncated a stack address with `mov edi,esi` instead of `mov rdi, rsi`. And if you fix that then you fall off the end of your code into garbage instructions because you don't make an `exit` system call. You're already running this inside gdb, use it!

---

> I tested it out with gcc:  `gcc -o key key.o`
>
> I still get an error almost the same as the first one
>
> ```
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: 
> In function `_start':
> (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
> ```

No, that's a totally different error.  If you had exported `_start` correctly, you would have gotten an error for conflicting definitions of `_start` (between your code and the CRT start files).

This error is that the `_start` definition in `crt1.o` (provided by gcc) has a reference to `main`, but your code doesn't provide a `main`.  This is what happens when you try to compile a C or C++ program that doesn't define `main`.

To link with gcc, use `-nostdlib` to omit the CRT start files and all other libraries.  (i.e. link pretty much exactly like you were doing manually with `ld`.)

```
gcc -nostdlib -static key.o -o key   # static executable: just your code
```

Or dynamically linked without the CRT start files, using your `_start`.

```
gcc -nostdinc -no-pie key.o -o key
```

You can call libc functions from code linked that way, but only on Linux or other platforms where dynamic linking takes care of running libc initialization functions.

If you statically link libc, you can only call functions like printf if you first call all the libc init functions that the normal CRT startup code does.  (Not going into detail here because this code doesn't use libc)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Between *global* and *_start* must have a space. That is one of your problems.

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    xor eax,eax
    push rax
    ...
```

In addition, to get why the *segmentation fault* is happening, you have to debug it. You could look the assembly instruction that does the segfault.

```
x/5i $eip
```

Comment: That is his linker problem, but he did get it to run by linking differently and got a segfault.

Comment: I saw that with gcc he got an error, so he didn't build the executable. I think he still using the executable linked with ld. If you look the function where he has the segmentation fault is in "global_start" and not _start. Anyway, the segmentation fault is in his assembly code and it is not complete.